# How can I find the subscribe URL from the Google Calendar embed source code?

Tags: google-calendar, embed

If I have the embed HTML for a Google Calendar, can I extract the URL I would use to subscribe to the calendar?

For example:

Embed code (linebreaks added for clarity):

```
<html>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/hosted/example.com/embed?
             height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;
             src=example.com_ecafa7el7kc4du1ervkdff4x6a%40
             group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23AB8B00&amp;
             ctz=Pacific%2FApia"
        style=" border-width:0 " width="800" 
        height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
</html>
```

the juicy bit is `src=example.com_ecafa7el7kc4du1ervkdff4x6a%40group.calendar.google.com` but I can't seem to get it into a format I can use in **Add -> Add by URL** in my Google Calendar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the following URL:

> www.google.com/calendar/hosted/example.com/embed?height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=**example.com_ecafa7el7kc4du1ervkdff4x6a%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23AB8B00**&ctz=Pacific%2FApia

You want to place the bold part in one of these templates:

```
XML: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/HERE/public/basic
ICAL: http://www.google.com/calendar/ical/HERE/public/basic.ics
HTML: http://www.google.com/calendar/hosted/HERE/embed?src=HERE
```

instead of the word `HERE`.

For example, if you wanted to use XML, use:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/example.com_ecafa7el7kc4du1ervkdff4x6a%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic
```

This requires the calendar to be public, which I assume it is, since there is an embeded version of it available.

Comment: perfect! thanks. can you edit your answer to make it a little clearer that the "juicy bit" minus the `src=` from my example is the address to use "HERE"?

Comment: Confirming that this still works in 2014 and thanking you for an answer that's been useful to me more than once. :)

Comment: You can also just take the part in bold and paste it into Settings >> Add Calendar >> Subscribe to Calendar >> Add Calendar (text box). Then it will subscribe you.